# Android/Java- How to Check IMEI of Mobile is Genuine or Not?

Tags: android, api, imei

Is there any API to check IMEI of Mobile is Genuine or Not and provides information like manufacturer, model type etc?

Comment: If there was something I missed that your specifically looking for just let me know and I will try to add it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the IMEI using a Check Digit Algoithm such as Luhn's Algorithm, See Wikipedia for more information on the [IMEI Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity)  and [Lunh's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)

There are several registries for blacklisted devices, you can cache this database or query it on-demand to determine if the IMEI is blacklisted.

One such example of a registry for this information is the [Central Equipment Identity Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Equipment_Identity_Register)

To lookup the manufacturer it would be similar to looking up the corporation of a Media Access Control Address (MAC) for example [Wireshark's OUI Lookup](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html)

One such example of this for IMEI data is @ [IMEI Data](https://imeidata.net/)

What such registries do or anyone else for that matter is to utilize the [Type Allocation Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Allocation_Code) to determine the manufacturer, this is usually the initial 8 digits of the IMEI.